# how to delete letters from a string variable in bash?

Tags: bash

For example

```
var="         |"
```

and

```
var2="hello"
```

How do I delete number of space characters that equals to the length of var2?

So var will now be  `"    |"` instead of `"         |"`

I thought of doing something with `${#var2}` minus var but I don't know how to delete specific characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var=${var:${#var2}}
```

`${var:${#var2}}` expands to the characters in `$var` from index `${#var2}` onwards.  See [Extracting parts of strings (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Extracting_parts_of_strings).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun one:

```bash
echo "${var/${var2//?/?}/}"
```

- `${var2//?/?}` replaces every character in $var2 with the character "?"
- Then we use that string ("?????") as a pattern against $var, and we replace it with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You can remove one space at a time while the $var is longer:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
var="         |"
var2=hello
expect="    |"

while (( ${#var} > ${#var2} )) ; do
    var=${var#\ }
done

[[ $var = $expect ]] && echo Ok
```

or you can calculate the number of characters to remove and use the offset parameter expansion to skip them:

```bash
remove_length=$(( ${#var} - ${#var2} ))
var=${var:$remove_length}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

s1='      |'  # 6 spaces
s2='hello'    # 5 characters

(( to_remove=${#s2}+1 ))

echo "${s1:$to_remove}"  # 5 characters removed
# ' |'
```